# I want to subtract each column from the previous non-null column using the diff function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long list of columns and I want to subtract the previous column from the current column and replace the current column with the difference. 
So if I have:

```
A   B   C   D
1  NaN  3   7
3  NaN  8   10
2  NaN  6   11
```

I want the output to be:

```
A   B   C   D 
1  NaN  2   4
3  NaN  5   2
2  NaN  4   5
```

I have been trying to use this code:
 df2 = df1.diff(axis=1)
but this does not produce the desired output

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include more than one row for your output to make any sort of sense.

Comment: Edited now, hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `df.where` and then `update` to bring back the first `non-null` entry for each row of your `DataFrame`.

#### Sample Data: `df`

```
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  NaN  3.0  7.0
1  1.0  4.0  5.0  9.0
2  NaN  4.0  NaN  4.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  3.0  7.0
5  3.0  NaN  NaN  7.0
6  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

#### Code:

```
df_d = df.where(df.isnull(), 
                df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).diff(axis=1))
df_d.update(df.where(df.notnull().cumsum(1).cumsum(1) == 1))
```

#### Output: `df_d`

```
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  NaN  2.0  4.0
1  1.0  3.0  1.0  4.0
2  NaN  4.0  NaN  0.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0
5  3.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
6  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is producing the desired result but you are trying to calculate diff on `nan` values which will be `nan` so diff is working as expected. 
For your case just fetch the first column from original dataframe and you should be fine

```
df2=df1.diff(axis=1) 
df2.A=df1.A

print(df2)
```

Output

```
A   B   C   D
1   NaN 2.0 4.0
```